# requiring vscode in a vscode extension

Tags: electron, vscode-extensions

I'm making an application with Electron that should be extendable. As a framework for how this is done, I have been digging in to the VSCode extension API. I think I have it figured out now except for one small thing. To use the API, an extension should start by requiring vscode: `const vscode = require('vscode')`

However, I can not find the module that this refers to in my hello-world extension's node_modules or in npm. How is VSCode providing the API module to the extension?

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code intercepts calls to `require` made by extensions. If an extension calls `require('vscode')`, VS Code returns the api object: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8a7961905611212bf6da6ba9ba6e5bf1f48d2943/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostRequireInterceptor.ts#L85

This means there is no corresponding `vscode` file on disk or under `node_modules` (only the typings are installed under `node_modules`)

Comment: That explains it :). Thanks!